# Java @requestBody doesn't work, dto empty

Tags: java, spring-boot

For some reason java can't map DTO with requestBody and all values are default ones, as for request it works, with payload for ex. `"{"productId":1,"commitment":6,"returnMonths":"2"}"`

DTO

```
 @Data
    public class Request {
        private int productId;
        private int commitment;
        private String returnMonths;
    
        // contructers
    }
```

Controller :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/calculate", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String calculatePrice(@RequestBody Request request) {
        productService.calculatePrice(request);
        return "Success";
    }
```

front request:

```
submit: async function() {
      let request = {
        productId: this.productSelected,
        commitment: this.optionSelected,
        returnMonths: this.input
      };
      let data = await getCalculation(request);
      console.log(data);
    }
```

DTO maps as:
productId : 0
commitment : 0
returnMonths : null

Comment: "*Java @requestBody doesn't work, dto empty*" - what exactly it says, why it does not work? please include the stack trace.

Comment: added  @GiorgiTsiklauri

Comment: I have a feeling, that you are not passing an appropriate `Content-type: application/json` header.

Comment: does front end sent Content-type: application/json on header and send http post?

Answer (score 1):

Tried an exact copy of your code and it worked when tested with Postman. This makes me think it's either something to do with the FE or maybe some issue in the service. I'd check if the Frontend really sends the data.

Comment: I tried as well from swagger and postman, both have trouble

Answer (score 0):

Try to annotation Request class with @AllArgsConstructor like:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
 @Data
    public class Request {
        private int productId;
        private int commitment;
        private String returnMonths;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your request body contains properties that is date such as `LocalDateTime`, make sure to format it in your `DTO` using `@JsonFormat(pattern="")` respecting the input value.